# Creating associative array of 2 files in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am making login system in php on localhost.

When a new user is registrated,
-the username is stored in /registration/usernames.txt,
-the password is stored in /registration/passwords.txt
When I write these into files `usernames.txt` and `passwords.txt`, I do it like this:

```
fwrite( $file_usernames, $usernameR.', ' );
fwrite( $file_passwords, $passwordR.', ' );
```

so when:

```
Username: John
Password: blablabla
```

is entered, it is stored in file usernames.txt as:

```
John,
```

and in passwords.txt it is stored as:

```
blablabla,
```

Now, when I want to login any of registered users, first I want to make an associative array where "key" is an username and the "value" is a password and then loop in the array and find if Username and Password is correct.

I tried to do it like this:

```
// create array of: "username" => "password"
$file_usernames_read = fread( fopen( "./registration/usernames.txt", "r" ), filesize( "./registration/usernames.txt" ) );
$file_passwords_read = fread( fopen( "./registration/passwords.txt", "r" ), filesize( "./registration/passwords.txt" ) );

$usernames = array( $file_usernames_read );
$passwords = array( $file_passwords_read );
$together = array_combine( $usernames, $passwords );
```

But it didn't work this way and I don't what other way I can try that.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```php
$usernames = explode(", ", file_get_contents("./registration/usernames.txt"));
$passwords = explode(", ", file_get_contents("./registration/passwords.txt"));

$map = array_combine($usernames, $passwords);
```

But in general you should encrypt the passwords (using [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php)) before storing them in the text file.

And you should also consider using a database system to store user data, instead of plain text files.

Comment: i will let you know later, when i am on pc, if it works.. and yes, i know.. this is just for practicing.. thank you